# Why do my ListView items overlap instead of scroll?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-scrollview

From my knowledge ListView should be scrollable without any tweaking needed, while my items just keep on overlapping over the listview boudaries. I have tried:

- adding android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" to listview child
- setting a linearlayout over the listview and setting layout weight to 1
- adding ScrollView on top of listview

but nothing worked.

Here is my layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListOfChatsActivity">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/slika1" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="126dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textColor="@color/logoBlue"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/picture"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/picture"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/picture" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/email"
        android:textColor="@color/logoBlue"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/phone"
        android:textColor="@color/logoBlue"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/email"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/email"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/email" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tptp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:background="@color/logoBlue"
        android:text="@string/contacts"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline3" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tptp"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a height to your listview other than wrap_content, else your listview will want to make your root layout scrollable if there are too many rows and they may overlap.

Comment: After a bit of tweaking it worked. Though just to check, isn't it now fixed for one screen size?

Comment: If you put some dp value, yes it's only for one screen. You should use percentage values with ConstraintLayout roots, or some other design application.